# Spectrum of operator on $L^2([0,1])$

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

I need to calculate the spectrum of the operator $T$ for $f \in L^2([0,1])$ defined by:

\begin{equation}
(Tf)(x) = \int_0^1 (x+y)f(y)dy.
\end{equation}

I know that $T$ is compact and self-adjoint so the residual spectrum is empty and the eigenvalues are real and a closed subset of $[-||T||, ||T||]$.

So I let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue so I know that $\lambda f(x) = (Tf)(x)$. By differentiating twice, I found that $\lambda f''(x) = 0$ but I don't really know how I can continue.

Comment: Just an idea: Does the Laplacian for (Tf) tell you anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that the range of $T$ is the span of $\{1,x\}$, that is is the space of linear functions on $[0,1]$. So if $f(y)=ay+b$ is an eigenvector of $T$ corresponding to $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$,
$$
(\frac12 a+ b)x + (\frac13 a + \frac12b) = \lambda a x + \lambda b
$$
Thus
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac12-\lambda & 1\\
\frac13 & \frac12-\lambda
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
a\\
b
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 0\\0\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: I wonder who tried to prove his ignorance by downvoting this answer...

Comment: So the eigenvalues are equal to $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ and $\frac{1}{2} -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$?

Comment: @Mee98 that looks better than before...

Comment: @ Mee98 yes, they are. @ Thomas, I had to add more because someone had penalize me for some reason. Thanks.

Comment: $0$ is also in the spectrum so, this answer is not quite correct (although I did not downvote it!) @OliverDiaz

Comment: @qbert Sorry, but this is nitpicking. If you know that this operator has two dimensional image then it is obvious that is has a non-trivial kernel. The answer shows nicely the non-trivial part of the spectrum (esp if you know -- like mentioned already in the question -- that the spectrum is real and closed).

Comment: @Thomas yes, it is obvious, but absolutely should be mentioned. Indeed, I think the OP is misunderstanding currently, "the eigenvalues are equal to ___ and ____"

Comment: @qbert kopfschüttel.

Comment: @Thomas perhaps one could even assume it was obvious that the OP knew the operator had finite dimensional range and write nothing at all. Indeed, that is probably the easiest way to show this operator is compact.

Comment: @OliverDiaz $0$ is an eigenvalue with infinite multiplicity. As the OP mentioned, the residual spectrum is empty. I think the OP really just wanted to compute the spectrum. Anyway, I must get off I forgot how aggravating trying to be helpful on this site can be. +1 to your answer regardless

Answer (score 2):

To continue on your path, note that *once you have justified* that $f$ must in fact be smooth to be an eigenvector for nonzero eigenvalue $\lambda$, you can differentiate twice as you did and note that 
$$
\lambda f''(x)=0
$$
In general, you are a long way from being allowed to differentiate an arbitrary element of $L^2$, so beware in the future.

So that, for $\lambda\ne 0$, by solving the ode $f(x)=ax+b$. Now proceed as in the other (hint, when does that system have a nontrivial solution?).

The point $\lambda=0$ is also in your spectrum however (this is of course obvious when noting that we took an infinite dimensional space to a finite dimensional one). For an explicit example, note that $Tf(x)=0$ where $f(x)=6x^2-6x+1$. This answer was arrived at by looking for a quadratic polynomial orthogonal to both $1$ and $y$.